# Get one to Many records in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**What am I trying?**

Get a particular category and it's associated Sub Categories

---

**Category Model**

```
class Category_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblcategory";
    protected $primaryKey = "CategoryID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Skill\SubCategory_Model');
    }
}
```

---

**Sub Category Model**

```
class SubCategory_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblsubcategory";
    protected $primaryKey = "SubCategoryID";
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

---

**Action Method**

```
public function SubCategories($category)
{
    $Categories = \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model
                  ::where("Category", "=", $category)
                  ->Subcategories;
    dd($Categories);
}
```

**When I run the code. I get below error**

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'tblsubcategory.category__model_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select *
>   from `tblsubcategory` where `tblsubcategory`.`category__model_id` = 1
>   and `tblsubcategory`.`category__model_id` is not null)

Comment: It seems that SubCategories must have `belongsTo` method defined

Comment: @GinoPane No, it doesn't *have* to, but it is good practice. Helper, what is the column that links a `subcategory` to its `category`?

Comment: @TimLewis I believe, that second parameter must be defined if foreign keys have non-conventional names or sth like that. Actually combination of `hasMany` and `belongsTo` always works for me, that's why I'm suggesting to try it.

Comment: @GinoPane Yes, you are correct about the naming. I was merely stating that you don't *need* to define the inverse. I suspect the column name isn't `category_model_id`, but more likely `category_id`

Comment: I am trying category record and also it's sub categories. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @TimLewis, yep. And, actually, maybe it is the reason. Helper, check this piece of documentation: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. Make sure that your tables have proper column names. And if not, then define foreign and local key names explicitly as `hasMany` second and third parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the comments, it is most likely that your `subcategory` table doesn't have a `category_model_id` but likely a `category_id`. By default, Laravel tries to extrapolate the name of the foreign column from the model name (in this case `Category_Model`, which explains the `category_model_id`. Changing the class to:

```
class Category_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "tblcategory";
    protected $primaryKey = "CategoryID";
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('\App\Models\Skill\SubCategory_Model', 'category_id')->get(); // Or whatever the column is actually called
    }
}
```

should solve the issue.

To return both the `category` object and its `subcategories`, change the action code to:

```
public function SubCategories($category)
{
    $Categories = \App\Models\Skill\Category_Model
                  ::where("Category", "=", $category)
                  ->with("Subcategories")
                  ->first();
    dd($Categories);
}
```

The `$Categories` should also now contain a `Subcategories` object, accessed via `$Categories->Subcategories`, which should return a collection of  `Subcategory` objects. If you wanted to see each one, you would loop through with a `foreach`

```
foreach($Categories->Subcategories AS $Subcategory){
  echo $Subcategory->name;
  // etc etc.
}
```

Comment: This returns only Sub Category Model Object. Whereas, I want to get category Object and that object should also hold sub category array.

Comment: There, that should return both the parent object and each of its `Subcategory` objects.

Comment: Now, I can see Category Object. but the Sub Category array is blank.

Comment: Hmm. Are there entries in the database for `subcategories` that link to your chosen `category`? I.E. if `categories.id` is 7 then `tblsubcategories.category_id` is also 7?

Comment: I know of a way to do that in Laravel 4.2, but that doesn't work in 5.1... I usually add an invalid `->select()` to the start of a query (like `->select("bs_column_name")` ) and read the raw `sql` in the error message output.